Mocking API requests with fetch(node-fetch) or fetch-mock in jest
I am trying to simulate an api request using either fetch from node-fetch or fetchMock from fetch-mock. I have tried using different import methods(CommonJS imports and ESModules import). I have tried adding different configurations for jest to recognize the import which I think is being made inside of the node-fetch/fetch-mock libraries. I suspect the issue might be the enzyme version I'm using. But here is the relevant part of my code:
import * as actionTypes from './uiActionTypes';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { dispatch } from 'react-redux';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

export const login = (email, password) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.LOGIN,
        user: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }
};

export const loginRequest = (email, password) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch(login(email=email, password=password));
            const response = await fetchMock.get('../../dist/login-success.json');
            const data = await response.json()

            dispatch(loginSuccess())
        } catch(error) {
            dispatch(loginFailure())
        }
    }
}

And here is the jest error:
 FAIL  src/actions/uiActionCreators.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/benoni/Desktop/ALX/alx-react/0x07-react_redux_action_creator_normalizr/task_7/dashboard/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9
    import http from 'node:http';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      2 | import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
      3 | import { dispatch } from 'react-redux';
    > 4 | import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
        | ^
      5 |
      6 | export const login = (email, password) => {
      7 |     return {

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/fetch-mock/cjs/server.js:9:10)
      at Object.require (src/actions/uiActionCreators.js:4:1)
      at Object.require (src/actions/uiActionCreators.test.js:1:1)

I have tried using CommonJS import syntax(const fetch = require('node-fetch');
I have tried adding the following configs
jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
    // ... other Jest config options
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'], // Optional, can be removed if all modules need transformation
  };

package.json:
"jest": {
    "config": "./config/jest.config.js",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss|png|jpg)$": "<rootDir>/config/styleMock.js"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/config/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "transform": {}
  },


Why you have two jest configs? Use only one jest config and try again.
